# definition of circular/directional random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, circular-statistics, measure-theory

I wanted to ask you to check my definition of circular random variable since i have never seen any.
So based on the assumption, that difference between linear and circular variables, is that c.r.v. takes values on the unit circle, that my variation of its definition is the following:

Definition: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space, and let $\Theta:\Omega\rightarrow[0,2\pi)$ is such mapping, that $\forall \theta \in [0,2\pi)$ is valid 
$$\{\omega \in \Omega: 0<\Theta(\omega)\leq\theta \}=X^{-1}((0,\theta])\in\mathcal{A},$$
then we call $\Theta$ a circular random variable (or it´s $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function).

Is it correct, or is there some kind of mistake? Cause, it seems pretty good to me.

Comment: See if it applies to known examples like (wind) direction (degrees from north), hour of day, etc. This is not sufficient, but a good start to find errors/build confidence in your definition. A key characteristic of circular variables is that values can be close together even if they have very different values, e.g. 1° east of north and 1° west of north, or 1 minute before 12 and 1minute after 12.

Comment: So,what should i add or change? i kind of can´t see it.

Comment: It might be better to think of $\Theta:\Omega\to S^1$ where $S^1 = \{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\}$. That eliminates the arbitrary parameterization of the angle (and the attendant possibility of making errors with inequality signs in the definition) and exposes the basis for calling this a "circular" random variable. The generalization to spherical random variables in higher dimensions is immediate.

Comment: Could we say then, if we would equip the topological space $S^{1}$ with sigma algebra and also the $\Sigma,$ we should be able to speak about measurability of this function, right? More precisely, would it be possible to talk about Lesbegue measurability with the right $\sigma$ - algebras?